# react native fresh install build fails with Undefined symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've been having an issue building my RN app for iOS.  To eliminate my own code as a problem I created a fresh project but I'm getting the same errors. I did the following (I am using a Macbook Pro with the M1 chip):

- added a fresh install using `npx react-native init TestProject`
- did a `pod update` successfully
- added a .swift file in the root of the project in xcode to create the bridging header
- cleaned the build folder
- tried `npx react-native run-ios` but that failed, so I tried to run from xcode and it also failed

The problem appears to be with linking, here are some warnings I get:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation' 
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
```

then has an error at the bottom saying `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1` with about 23 errors listed, all saying `Undefined symbol` followed by a bunch of Swift methods.

Initially I thought it was an issue with how I configured my app, but since the same problem happens with a fresh install, I really have no idea where to go from here.

I've searched all over and tried all sorts of things like legacy build mode, changing all sorts of build settings, but nothing worked.  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using the following:

- xcode 12.4
- nodejs v16.0
- npm v7.10.0
- react v17.0.1
- react-native v0.64.0

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting my app to build by using Rosetta2 for everything. This is what I had to do:

- I opened the terminal using Rosetta2
- deleted the node_modules directory
- deleted Pods directory
- deleted podfile.lock
- ran `npm install` and `pod install` using the Rosetta2 terminal

Once I did that, `npx react-native run-ios` builds successfully.

I should mention that when I tried to build using Flipper, the build failed. When I remove `use_flipper!()` from my Podfile, that's when my build succeeded.

I guess that software packages still haven't caught up to be compatible with M1 chips, so for now Rosetta2 is the solution.